# "inStream parameter is null" Server Error(REST API)

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I want to convert an old application to a new one in which i make HTTP calls (GET/POST/DELETE). I have a model package where i have my POJO classes and i made a DTO package where i have Dto classes. When i make a simple GET method to take a String message as a response i dont have any problem but when i use dependency injection and i want to use GET or POST methods to see some details about my app i get in postman  this message: **inStream parameter is null**

**OwnerResource.java**

```
        @Path("ownerResource")
        public class OwnerResource {
        
            @GET
            public Response ping() {         // When i use only this method i dont have any problem and i can see the message
                return Response
                        .ok("pang")
                        .build();
            }
        
// When i use the below code i have problem in HTTP calls
          
            @Inject
            private OwnerService ownerService;
        
            @GET
            @Path("owner/{ownerId}")
            @Produces("application/json")
            public RestApiResult<PropertyOwnerDto> getOwner(@PathParam("ownerId") int ownerId) {
                return ownerService.getOwner(ownerId);
        
            }
        
            @POST
            @Path("owner")
            @Produces("application/json")
            @Consumes("application/json")
            public void createNewOwner(PropertyOwnerDto owner) {
            ownerService.createPropertyOwner(owner);
    
        }
}
```

**PropertyOwner.java**

```
   @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity(name = "propertyowner")
    @Table
    public class PropertyOwner extends PersistentClass {
      // id is in PersistenceClass
      private int vat; 
      private String name;
      private String surname;
      private String address;
      private String phoneNumber;
      private String email;
      private String username;
      private String password;
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
      private List<Property> properties;
    
      public PropertyOwner(int vat, String name, String surname, String address, String phoneNumber, String email, String username, String password) {
        this.vat = vat;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
  }

}
```

**PropertyOwnerDto.java**

```
@Data@Getter@Setter
public class PropertyOwnerDto {

    private int vat;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public PropertyOwnerDto() {

    }

    public PropertyOwnerDto(PropertyOwner propertyOwner) {
        this.vat = propertyOwner.getVat();
        this.name = propertyOwner.getName();
        this.surname = propertyOwner.getSurname();
        this.address = propertyOwner.getAddress();
        this.phoneNumber = propertyOwner.getPhoneNumber();
        this.email = propertyOwner.getEmail();
        this.username = propertyOwner.getUsername();
        this.password = propertyOwner.getPassword();

    }

    public PropertyOwner asOwner() {
        PropertyOwner propertyOwner = new PropertyOwner();
        propertyOwner.setVat(vat);
        propertyOwner.setName(name);
        propertyOwner.setSurname(surname);
        propertyOwner.setAddress(address);
        propertyOwner.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        propertyOwner.setEmail(email);
        propertyOwner.setUsername(username);
        propertyOwner.setPassword(password);
        return propertyOwner;

    }
```

**OwnerService.java**

```
public interface OwnerService {

    
    void createPropertyOwner(PropertyOwnerDto ownerDto);
    
    RestApiResult<PropertyOwnerDto> getOwner(int ownerId);

}
```

**OwnerServiceImpl.java**

```
public class OwnerServiceImpl implements OwnerService {

    private final Properties sqlCommands = new Properties();

    {
        final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        try ( InputStream config = loader.getResourceAsStream("sql.properties")) {
            sqlCommands.load(config);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOError(e);
        }
    }
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OwnerServiceImpl.class);

    @Inject
    private PropertyOwnerRepository propertyOwnerRepository;

    @Inject
    private PropertyRepository propertyRepository;

    @Inject
    private RepairRepository repairRepository;

// SOME OTHER CODE HERE // 

   @Override
    public RestApiResult<PropertyOwnerDto> getOwner(int ownerId) {
        PropertyOwnerDto ownerDto = new PropertyOwnerDto(propertyOwnerRepository.findById(ownerId));
        return new RestApiResult<PropertyOwnerDto>(ownerDto, 0, "successful");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerNewPropertyDto(PropertyDto propertyDto) {
        propertyRepository.create(propertyDto.asProperty());
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

I use WILDFLY as application server.

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` in your deployment? I don't see any bean defining annotations on `OwnerService` or `OwnerServiceImpl`.

Comment: I fixed my post and you can see my beans.xml. I dont know if i have to configure something there

Comment: You need to add scopes to those two types.